# I want to pack the bits based on arbitrary mask

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's say that data is `1011 1001` and the mask is `0111 0110`, then you have:

```
input data:       1011 1001
input mask:       0111 0110
apply mask:       0011 0000 (based on `input mask`)
bits selected:    -011 -00- (based on `input mask`)
right packed:     ---0 1100
expected result:  0000 1100 (set left `8 - popcount('input mask')` bits to zero)
```

So the final output is `0000 1100` (note that the 3 positions on the left which are unspecified are zero-filled).

You can see that wherever the bits in `input mask` is 1 the corresponding value in `input data` is *selected* (in `bits selected` above) and then all *selected* bits are packed contiguously started in the least significant bits of the result (as shown in `right packed` above). Finally, any leftmost bits which are left over after the packing are set to 0 (there will be `8 - popcount(mask)` such bits).

Obvious choice is rotate and select but that will consume 5 operations as mask has 5 bits. Can I do this in one step?

**Note:**

1. The mask can be anything with arbitrary `n` bits `ON` (In above
   example `n=5`). All you know is the number of bits that are `ON` in
   the mask and the mask itself. Mask will keep on changing with `n` bits `ON`.
2. In above example I have used data and mask of 8-bits but in real
   usage it can be 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128 bits.

Comment: What do you mean "moved to right hand side?" What is the output if the mask is 0111 0111?

Comment: So other examples would be `1101 0010` with mask `0001 1111` -> `0001 0010` and data `1101 0010` mask `1111 1000` -> `0001 1010`? And since the mask has 5 `1` bits, the high 3 bits of the result will always be `0`?

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you're trying to do if you'd include the existing (5-operation) code as an example in your question.

Comment: In fact, the question was a bit clearer when looking at the original (unformatted) text, but I think the author wasn't familiar enough with markdown to have that carry though to the formatted question. I added the correct formatting and further clarified the question (in fact, this is a reasonably well-known bit manipulation algorithm, and the inverse of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568134/expand-right-bitwise-algorithm)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shift masked bits to the lsb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282869/shift-masked-bits-to-the-lsb)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're targeting `x86` most compilers will have an instrinsic for the `pdep` ([parallel bit deposit](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html)) instruction which directly performs the operation you want, in hardware, at a rate of 1 per cycle (3 cycles latency)<sup>1</sup>, on Intel hardware that supports it. For example, gcc [offers it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html#x86-Built-in-Functions) as the `_pdep_u32` and `_pdep_u64` intrinsic functions.

Unfortunately, on AMD Ryzen (the only AMD hardware that supports BMI2) this operation is very slow: one per 18 cycles. You might want to have a separate code-path to support non-Intel platforms if they are important to you.

If you aren't on `x86`, you can find general purpose implementations of these options [here](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e) - the specific operation you want is `expand_right` - and this other section will probably be of great interest in that it specifically covers the simple case where you are dealing with word-sized elements.

In practice, if you are really dealing with 8-bit data and mask values, you might just use a precomputed lookup table - either a big 8 bit x 8 bit = 65k one which covers all `{data, mask}` combinations and which gives you the answer directly, or a 256-entry one which covers all `mask` values and gives you some coefficients for a simple bit-shifting calculation or a multiplication-based code.

FWIW, I'm not sure how you can do it easily with 5 rotate instructions, because it seems that the naive solution needs 1 rotate instruction for each bit, whether set or not (so for a word size of 8 bits, 7 or 8 rotate<sup>2</sup> instructions).

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, the performance in principle depends on the hardware, but on all the mainstream Intel CPUs that implement it, it's 1 cycle throughput, 3 cycles latency (not sure about AMD).

<sup>2</sup> Only 7 rotates because the "rotate of 0" operation for the lowest order bit can evidently be omitted.

Comment: 5 rotations referred to the example mask with five up bits. (And the author indicated that this was entirely arbitrary.)

Comment: @n.caillou - understood, but I assume the mask is variable, both in the number of 1 bits and in their position, so it isn't obvious to me how you write code to uses N rotations for an N bit mask. Of course, it's is possible, e.g., with "count leading zeroes" or "find first 1" type instructions, but then you should use `pdep` or equivalents and I don't think that's what the author was talking about.

Comment: @n.caillou - BTW, I interpreted the author's final statement (_Note: the mask is arbitrary with 5 bits on._) not as 5 on bits being arbitrary, but rather as "The mask will always have exactly 5 set bits, but which bits are set is arbitrary" - but that doesn't seem like a particularly easier problem to solve than the one where the mask is totally arbitrary.

Comment: @BeeOnRope the number of bits can be anything. I will update the question

Comment: @pra - OK, makes sense. My answer generally applies to any number of on bits.