# How to replicate PEXT (parallel bit extract) with basic bitwise ops?

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation, intel, bitwise-operators

I'm porting some code from Rust to Swift and I noticed they use pext method to do some bit manipulation. Since it's an Intel instruction I can't get that into my Swift code so I was wondering what set of bitwise instructions (that I can use in Swift) would be able to get the same result as a `PEXT` operation.

For more context, here is a description of [`PEXT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#Parallel_bit_deposit_and_extract)

Basically it uses a mask that maps high order bits to contiguous lower order bits and clears the higher order bits in the final output. Example:

```
source = 1011 1110 1001 0011
mask =   0110 0011 1000 0101 

s = pext(source, mask)

s -> 0000 0000 0011 0101
```

I know replicating an advanced instruction is a performance hit but I'm really just trying to get the code to work.

Comment: [Shift masked bits to the lsb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28282869/995714), [pack the bits based on arbitrary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617369/995714)and [the reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47692902/995714)

Comment: Well, there're two built-in functions named `_pext_u32` and `_pext_u64` in Swift, but they're defined for Intel architecture only.

Comment: @user28434 how do you access those in swift? I can't find them

Comment: @swigganicks, it's in `simd` module.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The first "shift masked bits to the lsb" aka "compress right" is all I need right? What are the other two operations you linked for?

Comment: [Standard C++11 code equivalent to the PEXT Haswell instruction (and likely to be optimized by compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144237/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LưuVĩnhPhúc answer was correct. It's wildly inefficient on non-Intel architecture though so I would advise others looking to incorporate BMI2 instructions into Swift code to only do so when targeting macOS